# get parse String inside .then() to outside as JSX element

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, fetch-api

In react I import these following libraries

```
import React from "react";
import {
  Container,
  Row,
  Col,
  Card,
  CardBody,
  CardFooter,
  Badge,
  Button
} from "shards-react";
```

inside the functions, I have the following fetch method and inside .then() I add JSX elements

```
     output=''
fetch(
          "https://api.rss2json.com/v1/api.json?rss_url=https://medium.com/feed/@MediumStaff"
        )
          .then(res => res.json())
          .then(data => {
            const res = data.items; 

            let a = 0;
            res.forEach(item => {

              if (a === 0 || a === 3 || a === 6 || a === 9) {
                output += `<Row>`;
              }

              output += `<Col lg="6" md="6" sm="12" className="mb-4">
                <Card small className="card-post card-post--1">
                  <div
                    className="card-post__image"
                    style={{ backgroundImage: "url("+"${item.thumbnail}"+")" }}
                  >
                  </div>
                  <CardBody>
                  //JSX elements
                  </CardBody>
                </Card>
                </Col>`;
              if (a === 2 || a === 5 || a === 8 || a === 9) {
                output += `</Row>`;
              }

              a += 1;
            });

            document.querySelector(".blog__slider").innerHTML = output;
            console.log(output);

          });
```

In return I used the following code

```
<div className="blog__slider"></div>
```

I thought the functional component in React did not take output values as JSX components. If I get update output value outside of `.then()` I could use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: output}}`

Comment: You used Backticks to start the JSX-output. Which makes everything explicitly a string. Babel will not translate this. So just remove the ` and use ( and you are fine. Also don't use string concatenation (`+=`) push to an array and do `return output.join()` at the end.

Comment: Here's how to do this the React way: https://codesandbox.io/s/twilight-breeze-plbby

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a class component and add an array state inside the constructor of that class component. because when the class created that state will initiate. Using React Life cycle method componentDidMount fetch the JSON objects and push the JSON objects into the array state then you can use the JSX element in the render method

[codesandbox.io/s/twilight-breeze-plbby](https://codesandbox.io/s/twilight-breeze-plbby)